# Flutter overflow bottom when keyboard appears

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, overflow

i got this error and i cant get why, in a new screen i got a simple form on top (start of the column), when i focus the textfield the keyboard appears and overflow the date select and the button, but i dont know why.

Here is the initial state whiout focus on the textfield
[image]

and here is when i focus the textfield.
[image]

This is the widget i got to do this.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TopBarWidget(page: 'New Event', title: 'Nuevo Evento'),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                eDisplayName = value;
              },
              maxLength: 18,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              cursorColor: Color(0xFFFC4A1A),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Nombre del Evento",
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                OutlineButton(
                  focusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  highlightedBorderColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
                  child: Text('Cambiar Fecha'),
                ),
                Text(
                  "${formatedDate(selectedDate.toLocal())}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
                // Text("${selectedDate.toLocal()}"),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              disabledColor: Colors.grey[200],
              disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              onPressed: eDisplayName.length == 0
                  ? null
                  : () {
                      // print(newEvent);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
              child: Text(
                'ACEPTAR',
                // style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )),
);
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Yes! try the answer marked as correct, set to FALSE the resizeToAvoidBottomInset in your Scaffold()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo can set to false the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` in your `Scaffold()`

Like this

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: // ...
  // ...
)
```

Documentation reference: [Scaffold - resizeToAvoidBottomInset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I have added this but I still see the Bottom Overflowed issue

Answer (score 0):

It's beginner level problem. Don't know why most tutorial don't cover this problem before showing TextField Widget.

Column widget is fixed and does not scroll. So change Column to ListView. And do nothing else. The Widget will gain scroll feature and overflow problem will not happen anymore.

Comment: Actuality i alredy tried that, but if i use a ListWiew the button keeps getting hide with something that the keyboard moves up.
the resizeToAvoidBottomInset do the trick. thanks anyway

Comment: It's not that simple :) Spacer does not work in ListView